# How to save XML API data to database in WordPress once an hour for later use?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I manage the website for PAWS New England, an animal rescue organization who relies heavily on PetFinder. While PetFinder offers an iframe based widget for display your available animals, it breaks the responsive design of the site on smaller screens.

Because of this, I've built custom "Our Dogs" page by using PetFinder's API (XML based).

Unfortunately, the API can run pretty slow at times. I would like to pull data from the API once an hour and store it on the site's mySQL database (it's powered by WordPress), and run the custom page off that instead of the live API data. WordPress's "Transient API" seems like a perfect fit, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work.

After some searching, it seems like the problem may be in PHP's ability (or lack there of) to store XML data. In other words, I may need to convert the data to a string or array first.

I'm now officially stuck. Anyone have any insights on how to save XML data to the WordPress database once and hour, and access that data for use in a function?

Here's my existing code. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

function petf_shelter_list( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'shelter_id' => '1234',
        'api_key' => 'abcdef',
        'count' => 150,
        'status' => 'A'
    ), $atts ) );

    $xml = simplexml_load_file( "http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=" . $api_key . "&count=" . intval($count) . "&id=" . $shelter_id . "&status=" . $status . "&output=full" );

    // Stuff I do with $xml here...

}

add_shortcode('shelter_list','petf_shelter_list');

?>
```

Comment: you could setup a cron job, if you are allowed by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP's XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) to deal with the XML portion of your problem.

As for running something every hour, you need to setup a cron job to execute your desired script.

Comment: That's a good start. Thanks @mcryan. I'll try a few things and report back on how it works out.